# Plotting Values in Python

Tags: python, plot

I am new to Python and I'm working on plotting values onto a graph. It seems easy but it is very hard to extract values from a CSV file.

Here is what is going on:

- First, I do not need all values plotted. I have created a test excel sheet (CSV) to show you what I mean.
- I also need a new line (on the graph for every new line on excel)

----denoted by the different color highlights

Lets look at the photo to get a better understanding

```
Highlighted:
Light Blue= x-values for entire graph.
Green= y-values for first line.
Red= y-values for 2nd line.
Purple= y-values for 3rd line.
Etc.
```

I would like all these lines on one graph, and each line to be labeled with the values highlighted in grey (corresponding to the below set of y-values)

Here is what i have written so far, which isolated the values i need, I just do not know how to plot them.

Sorry for such a rough explanation 
Thank you

Comment: What is your question? And what do you mean by "highlights"? Can you please try to be more clear? We are not going to understand your personal terminology without at least showing us an example of the data.

Comment: Please post your code *as formatted text*,**not as images**

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas to read the csv file and matplotlib to plot the lines.

```
import pandas
import matplot.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.read_csv('./csv_file.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['Light Blue'], df['Green'], label='Green', color='green')
ax.plot(df['Light Blue'], df['Red'], label='Red', color='red')
ax.plot(df['Light Blue'], df['Purple'], label='Purple', color='purple')
ax.legend()
```

This is assuming the columns in the csv are labelled with 'Light Blue', 'Green', etc.